# Using Powershell to drop multiple rows from a csv based on multiple conditions

Tags: powershell, csv

I need to drop from multiple rows from a CSV. I've seen this code:

```
Get-Content "file.csv" | Where {$_.Column -ne "Known Value" |Export new.csv
```

But I can't figure out how to get it to work for my purposes. I have imported the CSV as a system object array. I am comparing all cells in the CSV to a hashtable as `@{"column": "values"}`. Anyone can go in and change these depending on what they need to remove from the CSV.

Here is the hashtable:

```
#data_entry.ps1 #file name

$remove_value_row = @{
    "First_Name" = @("Benjamin","Ben");
    "Last_Name" = @("Armour");
}
```

Here is my code:

```
#drop_rows.ps1
. .\data_entry.ps1

$csv = import-csv "\droprows.csv" 




$csv |Where-Object {
    for($i=0;$i -lt $csv.length;$i++){
            foreach($key in $remove_value_row.Keys){
            -not($remove_value_row[$key] -contains $csv[$i].($key))
            #drop where a csv column 1. matches a key ,
            #2. the cell value is one of the key-values.
                }
            }

} | Export "out.csv"
```

Comment: Hmmm. I'm curious to what the answer of this will be. I  instantiate an instance of the C# File Reader in Powershell when doing tasks like this so I can read line for line instead of using `Get-Content`.

Comment: Hi, your code is broken, please fix it. At least an `if` and a few brackets. I formatted the code so you can see it but your edit overwrote mine.

Comment: Thank you, I have added the missing brackets and taken away the extra parenthesis.

Comment: @sodawillow I see what you mean. I've fixed the grammar and made the code clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code enumerates the entire CSV per each row so for 10k rows it'll do 100 million iterations...

Let's start by simplifying the hashtable definition a bit since the field names don't contain spaces:

```
$remove_value_row = @{
    First_Name = "Benjamin", "Ben"
    Last_Name  = "Armour"
}
```

Now let's organize the pipeline properly: import - conditional filter - export

```
Import-Csv 'R:\input.csv' |
    Where {
        foreach ($remove in $remove_value_row.GetEnumerator()) {
            if ($remove.value -contains $_.($remove.name)) {
                return $false
            }
        }
        return $true
    } |
    Export-Csv 'R:\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```